# Why is my class creation being skipped

Tags: java, android, class, oncreate

Okay this error for the life of me I can't figure out, to the point where I don't even know what to google anymore. 
This is a fragment of my initial class. ([You can view the whole thing here](https://github.com/scorchgid/Avariel/blob/396d02b12b3cd71bd1dfc7cff32175ed9943a342/app/src/main/java/com/example/gideonsassoon/avariel/ui/MainFragmentActivity.java))

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("Avariel", "I am running");

        RealmManager realmManager = new RealmManager();

        Log.i("Avariel", "I have passed RM");
```

In it I am trying to create a class of Realm Manager ([You can view the whole class here)](https://github.com/scorchgid/Avariel/blob/396d02b12b3cd71bd1dfc7cff32175ed9943a342/app/src/main/java/com/example/gideonsassoon/avariel/database/RealmManager.java). At this point I can even get the `"I am running Realm Manager's on Create"`to show. When I debug it just freezes.

```
public class RealmManager extends Activity {

    public static final String TAG = MainFragmentActivity.class.getName();
    private Realm realm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.i("Avariel REALM", "I am running Realm Manager's on Create");
        /**
         * https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#getting-started
         * http://facebook.github.io/stetho/
         * https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm
         * chrome://inspect/#devices
         */
       /* Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
        Realm.init(this);
        Stetho.initialize(
                Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
                        .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
                        .enableWebKitInspector(RealmInspectorModulesProvider.builder(this).build())
                        .build());

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.beginTransaction();
        Player player = realm.createObject(Player.class);
        player = player.create(01, "Gideon", "Barlock", "Orc", "Lawful Evil", "Fighter", "A wandering Warrior", 0, 30, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        Realm.init(this);

        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();
    }
```

Meaning the log I see

```
05-27 22:38:13.477 32158-32158/com.example.gideonsassoon.avariel I/Avariel: I am running
05-27 22:38:13.559 32158-32158/com.example.gideonsassoon.avariel I/Avariel: I have passed RM
```

What have I done wrong here. [You can view the full project here](https://github.com/scorchgid/Avariel/tree/396d02b12b3cd71bd1dfc7cff32175ed9943a342)

Many thanks for your help,

Comment: Why does `RealmManager extends Activity`?

Answer (score 1):

*Never* create an instance of an `Activity` yourself via the constructor.

Since `RealmManager` does not seem to be an actual activity (with a UI and such), remove `extends Activity` from your declaration of `RealmManager`. Then, you need to arrange to call methods on your `RealmManager` yourself, like any other Java object.

Answer (score 0):

> "I am running Realm Manager's on Create"

No you aren't. You called `new`, which called the default constructor, which never calls `onCreate`.

Try the following to create a *regular Java object* that manages some Realm object

```
public class RealmManager  {

    private final Context context;
    private final Realm realm;

    public RealmManager(Context context) {
        Log.i("Avariel REALM", "I am running Realm Manager"); 
        context = context;
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }
```

Plus,

```
RealmManager realmManager = new RealmManager(this);
```

I believe all that other code belongs in an **`Application`** class, not any Activity

For example

- https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#best-practices
- https://facebook.github.io/stetho/#integrations